# Airplane Cylinder Modeling

Tags: modeling

Any tip to model something like this photo ? I'm new to Blender.

The top part of the cylinder with this curves looks like a nightmare to me.

I did the lower region with a cylinder mesh and loop cuts to add the details.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). I'm not sure which part you are reffering to, but there is a [detailed model of R-2800](https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/pratt-whitney-r-2800-3d-max/1007028) on Turbosquid including a [Wireframe preview](https://static.turbosquid.com/Preview/2016/02/17__02_06_47/PrattandWhitneyR28003dmodel52.jpg09a4545c-5c71-4ed9-8778-80a018a47e97Zoom.jpg).